# How to check keyboard input using new input system

Tags: unity-game-engine

Im kinda new to unity and Im trying to make a 2d top down game where the player can shoot in 4 directions(up,down,left,right) using the arrows. How do I check if Left Arrow is being pressed using new input system?

Edit: It seems that my question is not clear enough. 2D Top Down game where the player moves using WASD and shoots using Arrows (like in Hero Siege). I made 4 empty game objects for the shooting directions. I got stuck at getting the Arrow's input into unity so when I press Up Arrow the player will shoot upwards, Left Arrow for the left and so on.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Within the Input Actions window you need to setup a movement action as a vector.

[image: input]

In the code you can then get player input from the manager by registering to the event: `PlayerInputManager.onPlayerJoined`

```
PlayerInput playerInput;
void OnPlayerJoined (PlayerInput input) this.playerInput = input;
```

You can then define a move action which you find by name from the player input.

```
InputAction moveAction;
moveAction = playerInput.actions["Move"];
```

Read the value from the action as a vector. When it passes a threshold you can process some logic.

```
var moveDir = moveAction.ReadValue<Vector2>();
if (moveDir.sqrMagnitude > 0f) {
    // You're now moving!
}
```

Comment: I dont think that answers my question. Maybe I need to be more precise: when I press Left Arrow, the player shoots to the Left. Press Right shoot Right and so on. I dont see how can I use what you have answered to solve my problem.

Comment: @Pascu2001 You can use moveDir's x and y components to figure that out. Of course you could also simplify the problem by creating simple button actions (non vector). But that defeats the purpose of the new input system which allows you to use all kinds of controllers for the same actions.